# UVM: create a task that gets called every 100 or so cycles for all the component.

Tags: system-verilog, verification, uvm

For all my components (monitor, driver, sequencer etc.) I need to create a task that gets called every 100 or so cycle. 
I think there is a way to do this with custom phases but not sure how. Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo-multiple inherit feature introduced in 1800-2012 via "interface class" and "implements" is the best solution.
To satisfy your requirement, you can apply the design pattern of Observer. Below is an example code

```
interface class tick;
    pure virtual task trigger_tick(....);
end class

class observer extends uvm_components;
    ......
    tick tick_list[$];

    virtual function void register_tick(tick t);
        tick_list.push_back(t);
    endfunction 

    virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
        forever begin
            repeat(100) @(posedge top.clock);
            foreach (tick_list[i]) tick_list[i].trigger_tick();
        end
    endtask
end class

class my_component extends uvm_component implements tick;
......
    virtual task trigger_tick();
//do something
    endtask
end class
```

Then you can creat an instance of observer and register all components to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to implement custom phases for this. Here is an example of how you can do this.

```
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);

  forever begin  
    // wait for reset ....

    fork 
       your_task1();
    join_none

    // do other things .....
  end

endtask : run_phase

task your_task1(); // this task will keep running forever..

  int count=1; 
  forever begin
    @(posedge vif.clk);

    if(count%100 == 0)  // will be true only when count becomes multiple of 100
       your_task2();

    count++;
  end

endtask : your_task1

task your_task2(); // one which you wanted to call every 100 clk cycles
   // add your logic
endtask : your_task2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will work great for single instance. I need a generic solution that can be applied to all components.

Comment: You could create a base class and let your driver, monitor, sequencer components inherit from that. With SystemVerilog 2012 standard, you can achieve multiple inheritance by extending a class from more than one class using the "implements" keyword (similar to java). Check out this link http://cfs-vision.com/2016/03/10/multiple-inheritance-in-systemverilog/  But you need to have a simulator which supports this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add that logic in `run_phase` of every component in the following mannger.

```
task run_phase (uvm_phase phase);
  fork
    begin
      forever
      begin
        repeat (100) @(posedge virtual_interface.clk);
        your_task();
      end   
    end
    // Other threads
  join_none
  wait_fork;
endtask
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use uvm_events
like from each component generate the event at 100th cycle, and from your own class catch that event and call the task

Could you explain  why you need to run a task for each of the component? I guess you are debugging something, may be transaction recording or uvm_printer would be more helpful here